# PageSpeed Insights returns NOT_HTML error when I try to analyze a Shopify store

Tags: shopify, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

After November 15, 2021 update, PageSpeed Insights is returning following error whenever I try to analyze a Shopify store.

> Lighthouse returned error: NOT_HTML. The page provided is not HTML
> (served as MIME type text/plain) [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1MA1.png)

Kindly let me know if someone has figured that out. This is the link of the Shopify store that is in screenshot: https://hanora-fashion.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also having the same issue with Shopify sites I'm testing. I manage multiple sites and they all seem to be impacted.

I believe this is an issue with the new version of Lighthouse that they updated to as well based on release notes they moved to version 9.0.0 (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/release_notes).

Looks like there's an open Github issue: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/13379

UPDATE: Confirmed from a Tweet from SEO at Shopify that it's a Lighthouse issue and they're aware of it being worked on. Github issue has updated response from Lighthouse and Chrome Developer Tools Dev at Google that it's a priority that they're working on but no timeline.